# Microservices architecture event collaboration pattern

Tags: microservices, event-sourcing

Martin Fowler's description of the Event Collaboration pattern (https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventCollaboration.html) appears to imply that requisite external data (data from other services) that is needed for a service to function should be replicated and maintained within the service.

This seems to imply that we should not resort issuing explicit queries.
For example:

Say you have a communications service that is responsible for sending emails to clients and is dependent order information (that lives in the order service) to send an order confirmation email.

With Event Collaboration, the communications service will have some internal representation of all orders that it will have built up by consuming relevant order creation/modification events.

In this example a query to retrieve order details will not be necessary to generate the confirmation email.

Are there any instances in which we would use explicit query messages rather than data replication when adopting the Event Collaboration pattern?

Answer (score 0):

i think even in this case, what i would have done is create a consumer of OrderPlaced event in Order Microservice Only. That event processor will read all the details from order create a MailToBeSent event and write it on a Topic or Queue , which CommunicationService should listen and send the email.

Communication Service should not understand , how to create a email based on order(as core purpose of cummunication service is to send emails).

Design wise also communication service should not require to change every time you add a new service which want a mail sending functionality.